# Show PopupWindow above all window for target android 26

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-8.0-oreo

I want to show `PopupWindow` above all window (example: another popupwindow, dialog, another activity screen) without request `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` so I use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST`

```
public void showSimplePopupWindow() {
    final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout_2, null);

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView);
    ...config popup window...

    PopupWindowCompat.setWindowLayoutType(popupWindow, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.button_show_popup_window));
}
```

It working well **in all android version** if I set `targetSdkVersion < 26`  .

Currently, If I keep the code above and update the target `targetSdkVersion` to 26 then it will crash with **device api 25-26** with exception `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@859d91f is not valid; is your activity running?`

I see that `TYPE_TOAST` is deprecated in `sdk 26` and they suggest to use `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`. However, when I use `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`, `AndroidStudio` show `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` required api 26. Therefore, `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` only work well with device api 26, for device api < 26, it will crash ( even I have enabled `Display/Draw over other app` permission)
[image]

Is there any alternative way to make `TYPE_TOAST` work with target `api 26`? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: I know this is not a standard way, but using a transparent activity for showing popupWindow may help you in this case

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug with API 25. The bug is that if you change the target API to be 26, API 25 devices will no longer be able to use the TYPE_TOAST parameter, even though it is allowable in API 25.

The only way to fix this behavior is to have the user enable overlay permissions in Settings for your app. API 25 and 26 overlays will then function as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since:

- [TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY) (introduced in [Api level 26](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)) is a constant value 2038 (0x000007f6)
- [TYPE_TOAST](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_TOAST) (since Api level 1!) is a constant value 2005 (0x000007d5)

one option would be to [check the  System Version at Runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#version-codes) and, depending on its value, using the right constant.

Comment: thanks for your answer but when I use TYPE_TOAST with target version 26, the device with api 25 will crash

Comment: @PhanVanLinh why not using TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY when you detect at runtime the target version is 26?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand well your comment. If I set `target version is 26`, `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` only work well with device api 26, for device api < 26, it will crash. I have mentioned in the last past of my question

Comment: @PhanVanLinh the point of my answer is to determine the value of the parameter to pass at runtime, meaning to code the right value as being one or the other, depending on the API level detected at runtime.

Comment: @PhanVanLinh Meaning: your code pass to setWindowLayoutType an int. That int would be computed at runtime, as being 0x000007f6 or 0x000007d5, depending on the API value detected at runtime.

Comment: I think I'm seeing the same problem. Your suggested solution doesn't work because the issue depends on the `targetSdkVersion` set at compile time. If the target SDK is set to 26, the app crashes when ˚TYPE_TOAST˚ is used, no matter what Android version the device is running.

Comment: @FD_ OK. I don't have any more information on this: maybe it is time for setting a bounty on this question?